# Taking Table and Stratifying by Chosen Variable

Tags: r, summarize

Currently struggling getting this table reoriented because I am still new to R and tidying data. I have a small table of data on college admissions, and I want to stratify by department, having different percentages as new columns (desired outcome below).

This is what I have tried so far, providing me with the following output:

```
library(tidyverse)
ucb %>%
    group_by(Admit, Gender, n, Dept) %>%
    spread(key = Admit, value = n) %>%
    mutate(Prop_Admitted = Admitted / (Admitted + Rejected), 
           Prop_Rejected = Rejected / (Admitted + Rejected)) %>%
    head(n = 20)

# Output
Gender  Dept    Admitted    Rejected    Prop_Admitted   Prop_Rejected
<chr>   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
Female  A   89  19  0.82407407  0.1759259
Female  B   17  8   0.68000000  0.3200000
Female  C   202 391 0.34064081  0.6593592
Female  D   131 244 0.34933333  0.6506667
Female  E   94  299 0.23918575  0.7608142
Female  F   24  317 0.07038123  0.9296188
Male    A   512 313 0.62060606  0.3793939
Male    B   353 207 0.63035714  0.3696429
Male    C   120 205 0.36923077  0.6307692
Male    D   138 279 0.33093525  0.6690647
Male    E   53  138 0.27748691  0.7225131
Male    F   22  351 0.05898123  0.9410188
```

This is the table I am looking to end up with, with all of the respective values filled in, of course.

```
Dept    Female_Admitted Female_Rejected Male_Admitted   Male_Rejected   Male_Proportion_Admitted    Female_Proportion_Admitted
A   
B   
C   
D   
E   
F
```

I am just unsure how I can go from my code to having gender options as columns, thus eliminating the duplicate department letters. Any help is appreciated! Also I am trying to keep this in tidyverse, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pivot_wider` from the new `tidyr` which can take multiple `values_from` argument

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Gender, 
                       values_from = matches("Admitted$|Rejected"))

# A tibble: 6 x 9
#  Dept  Admitted_Female Admitted_Male Rejected_Female Rejected_Male
#  <fct>           <int>         <int>           <int>         <int>
#1 A                  89           512              19           313
#2 B                  17           353               8           207
#3 C                 202           120             391           205
#4 D                 131           138             244           279
#5 E                  94            53             299           138
#6 F                  24            22             317           351
# … with 4 more variables: Prop_Admitted_Female <dbl>,Prop_Admitted_Male <dbl>,
#   Prop_Rejected_Female <dbl>,Prop_Rejected_Male <dbl>
```

---

For the older version of `tidyr`, we can do

```
df %>%
   gather(key, value, -Gender, -Dept) %>%
   unite(key, Gender, key) %>%
   spread(key, value)
```

where `df` is

```
df <- ucb %>%
        group_by(Admit, Gender, n, Dept) %>%
        spread(key = Admit, value = n) %>%
        mutate(Prop_Admitted = Admitted / (Admitted + Rejected), 
               Prop_Rejected = Rejected / (Admitted + Rejected))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick rely; sadly I am working in an online notebook where I can not use new libraries other than provided. Is there a tidyverse solution that is similar?

Comment: You're the bomb; thank you! when you use gather, unite and spread, are you including the keys and values or are you letting it default?

Comment: In `gather(key, value, -Gender, -Dept)` you can use any name instead of `key`, `value` it will give that name to the column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with the tidyverse, but with `data.table` is pretty straight forward. I hope it helps:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt, dept ~ gender, sep = "_", value.var = names(dt)[3:6])
```

### Data used:

```
dt <- data.table(gender = c(rep("Female", 6), rep("Male", 6)), 
                 dept = rep(LETTERS[1:6], 2), 
                 Admitted = sample(1:100, 6, FALSE), 
                 Rejected = sample(1:100, 6), 
                 Prop_admitted = runif(6), prop_rejected = runif(6))
```

Comment: Appreciate it either way; since I am new, options are always a good thing. What is rep() doing here?

Comment: Everything after the **Data used** was aimed at creating some reproducible data, as I didn't have your `ucb` data. `rep` is used to create a vector by repeating a vector or a value a number of times, see `?rep`